# Can we restrict user to open visual studio solution in offline mode in TFS?

Tags: tfs

After downloading solution from source control and changing the location of solution developer should not open solution in visual studio.

Is it possible?if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

No, everyone can open the project/solution locally in Visual Studio via **Open** > **Project/Solution**.

According to your description, you have downloaded the project/solution source and changed the location. So, it can be considered as a local project/solution which is not in source control.

Comment: @Akshay It that answered your question? any update for this?